# Shoutcast | Jquery | Passing Variables

Tags: jquery, shoutcast

I am using a shoutcast library to retrieve stream information from my server including the current song played, last 10 songs played, and etc.. That all works fine.

## The code that jQuery uses to pull the current song played is below

```
<script>
        $.SHOUTcast({
            host : 'live.soundcheck.xyz',
            port : 8000,
            interval : 5000,
        }).stats(function(){
            $('#songtitle').text(this.get('songtitle'));
        });
    </script>
```

The code above puts the song title into an element named '#songtitle'.

==========

What I would like to do is place the songtitle into a LED scroller on the page. Here is the code for the scroller which works as default.

```
<embed src="http://www.satisfaction.com/led-scroller-generator/show.swf?       baseURL=http://www.satisfaction.com/led-scroller-generator/&clickURL=http://www.satisfaction.com/led-scroller-generator/&clickLABEL=LED Scroller Generator&flashLABEL=Satisfaction.com&delaySpeed=10&transID=0&str=(+ $track +)&bgColor=0&symbolX=9&w=3&h=3&pointType=point&glowColor=16711680&designNum=1" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="219" height="35" name="show" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

A snippet of the above code shows

```
&str=(+ $track +)&bgColor=0&symbolX=9&w=3&h=3&pointType=point&glowColor=16711680&designNum=1"
```

I need to be able to pass a variable to the 'str='above from jQuery. If I say str=HELLO the LED will scroll HELLO. I want the LED to scroll the current song being played which can be retrieved from jQuery.. I want something like str=variable (as the song will always be different)

Hope this isn't to confusing, thanks!

Regards,

Comment: You need to URL-encode URLs that are passed in the query string, and then encode the whole thing for usage in HTML.  From your snippet, it isn't clear to me what URL is what, and what you need to encode to insert where.

Answer (score 0):

Give your embed an id first:

```
<embed id='myEmbeddedObj' ... >
```

Then set it to some innocuous benign settings that won't error out and use `.attr()`.

Where you have

```
$('#songtitle').text(this.get('songtitle'));
```

In the above script you cited, replace With:

```
$("#myEmbeddedObj")[0].prop("baseURL") = "http://www.satisfaction.com/led-scroller-generator/&clickURL=http://www.satisfaction.com/led-scroller-generator/&clickLABEL=LED Scroller Generator&flashLABEL=Satisfaction.com&delaySpeed=10&transID=0&str=(" + this.get('songtitle') + ")&bgColor=0&symbolX=9&w=3&h=3&pointType=point&glowColor=16711680&designNum=1";
```